# Dovecot number of connections?

Tags: dovecot, imap

I am working on a Dovecot server. 
My main purpose is to count number of users who checks their e-mail daily. 
How can i count number of Imap connections?
I am new to these things by the way.

Comment: Do you want a snapshot, or a daily map, or a peak number? You are also aware that IMAP connections remain "open", unless something interupts them?

Comment: I am open to all analysis. I am aware of that thing. I looked at dovecot.log and imap connections recurring every minute.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: You may write a script to parse dovecot logs and find the unique users  within a certain timeframe (eg 1 day). This is in a similar way we parse sometimes apache logs to find unique addresses.

Comment: The log file is a great place to start, running cut to filter out the important columns, then sorting with `unique -c` would at least give you an idea of how many individual connections from unique people you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my RHEL6 box the dovecot IMAP logins are logged in /var/log/maillog.

Easy sailing from there if you want to write your own scripts.

Installing `logwatch` and the dovecot extension from [here](http://barry.coffeesprout.com/fix-dovecot-unmatched-entries-logwatch/) should result in a daily message to root like this one:

```
--------------------- Dovecot Begin ------------------------ 
 Dovecot IMAP and POP3 Successful Logins: 4395
 Dovecot disconnects: 4365 
 ---------------------- Dovecot End -------------------------
```

Comment: My IMAP logins are in dovecot.log so i cant see Dovecot section in Logwatch. Which .conf file should i look for?

Comment: add your custom logfile to /etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf with `Logfile = /path/to/dovecot.log`